# SQL Server 2019 - Issues querying where column data contains brackets "[" or "]"

Tags: sql-server, syntax, sql-like, brackets

I have two tables each containing a folder path column.  These columns may contain brackets (i.e. `Folder1\Folder2\Folder3[Old]\`). Joining the two table columns (`table1.path = table2.path`) will return all records that match from each table. However, there may be a need to find partial paths from one table that exist in another - but a query using a `Like` operator will ignore records with brackets:

```
select a.*
from table1 a
cross join table2
where a.path like '%' + b.path + '%'
```

This does not return the correct results. Is there an escape syntax that needs to be added?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I applied Dai's syntax and it works:

```
select a.*
from table1 a
cross join table2
where a.path like '%' + replace(replace(b.path, '[', '#['), ']', '#]') +  '%' escape '#'
```

Comment: Use `WHERE a.path LIKE '%' + REPLACE( REPLACE( b.path, '['', '#[' ), ']', '#]' )  + '%' ESCAPE '#'`.

Comment: You might want to move that gnarly `CONCAT( REPLACE( REPLACE(...` logic to a `DECLARE` statement located before your query - and to also let you inspect the actual LIKE pattern that's used in the end.

Comment: NOTE:  Not sure why I'm getting "duplicate" post notifications - I don't think my inquiry is similar to the suggested examples as the examples are looking for a specific term to filter/query whereas I'm looking to apply the escape clause to a column that may contain brackets.